# jQuery .data() remove item from stored array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using the .data() function in jQuery to store an array as per below:

```
var myArray = {};
myArray[0] = {};
myArray[0][0] = "test00";
myArray[0][1] = "test01";
myArray[1] = {};
myArray[1][0] = "test10";
myArray[1][1] = "test11";

$('#datastorage').data("testname". myArray);
```

I want to remove only one item (myArray[0]) from the "testname" and keep the rest.

The below does not work:

```
$('#datastorage').removeData("testname").removeData(0);
```

I believe jQuery stored the array in a form of a plain object (the test `$.isPlainObject()` comes back true)
I am now trying to use the function `.not()` to remove the element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the original object is an array, what's actually stored is just a reference to the original data, so any modification you make is reflected in *every* reference to that array, including the one stored in `.data()`.

So you can just remove the element from the array:

```
$('#datastorage').data("testname").shift();
```

or if you want more flexibility on which elements are removed, use `.splice()`.

```
$('#datastorage').data("testname").splice(0, 1);
```

or if you've still got access to `myArray`:

```
myArray.shift();
```

There's no need to put the array back into `.data()` - any of the above will modify both `myArray` and whatever's already in `.data()` - *they're the **same** array!*.

The same would apply if the data was an object, but not if it's a primitive type.

Comment: Thanks for that but I keep getting the following error:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'shift'"

Comment: @davidbayonchen  `var myArray = []`, not `{}`.

Comment: @davidbayonchen and if for some reason you _have_ to leave `data` as an object instead of an array, use `delete $('#storage').data('testname')[0]`.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak, that works fine. Would you recommend me to use Arrays [] instead of Objects ? {}

Comment: @davidbayonchen if your indices are all numbers, and they start with a low number (as your sample does) then you should use arrays.  Note however that `shift` and `splice` will renumber the remaining elements.  Using an `object` and `delete` will not.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to get the array out, remove from it, and then put it back.

```
var a = $('#datastorage').data('testname');

a.splice(0,1); // remove 1 item from position 0

$('#datastorage').data('testname', a);
```

Comment: I do get the following error message:
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'splice'"

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
var myArray = []; // myArray is an Array, not an object
myArray[0] = {};
myArray[0][0] = "test00";
myArray[0][1] = "test01";
myArray[1] = {};
myArray[1][0] = "test10";
myArray[1][1] = "test11";

$('#datastorage').data("testname", myArray);
console.log($('#datastorage').data("testname"));

$('#datastorage').data("testname", myArray.slice(1));
console.log($('#datastorage').data("testname"));
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nNg68/